# How to detect if we're on a UI thread?

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading, ui-thread

For the sake of argument, consider a UI thread as a thread that has had a call to `Application.Run()` or one of it's overloads called on it and has an active message loop running.

Is there a way of detecting if we're currently executing on such a thread?

The reason I want this is because I have a class with a private function that is long-running. The class itself is already multithreaded, and the usage of this class is such that it might be used from either the UI or from background threads doing processing. This function also falls into this net. But I don't want it to block up the UI thread. So I want to detect if I am running on a UI thread and if so, fork the function call into a background thread (probably `ThreadPool`, but that's a non-issue for this discussion). This is entirely well-behaved, but the background threads are probably relying on the output of the function, so blocking for them is better, whereas the UI thread is accessing it in a more "set-and-forget" manner.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would suggest that it's the kind of decision the caller should make. You could always write wrapper methods to make it easier - but it means that you won't have problems with the caller being in an "odd" situation (e.g. a UI framework you don't know about, or something else with an event loop) and you making the wrong decision for them.

If the method ever needs to provide feedback in the right thread, I'd pass in an `ISynchronizeInvoke` (implemented by `Control`) to do that in a UI-agnostic way.

Answer (score 13):

If you have access to a `Form` or a `Control`, you can check the [`InvokeRequired`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.invokerequired.aspx) property; this will return `false` if you are on the UI thread and `true` if you are not.. If it happens in a context where you cannot check against a `Control`, you could easily set up a static property in your program that you could check against. Store a reference to `Thread.CurrentThread` at startup, and compare `Thread.CurrentThread` to that reference when you need to know:

```
static class Program
{
    private static Thread _startupThread = null;

    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        _startupThread = Thread.CurrentThread;

        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }

    public static bool IsRunningOnStartupThread()
    {
        return Thread.CurrentThread == _startupThread;
    }
}
```

By calling `Program.IsRunningOnStartupThread` you will get a `bool` saying if you are or not.

Comment: The startupthread isn't necessarily the GUI thread, or the only GUI thread.

Comment: WRONG: InvokeRequired returns true if on a "different thread than the one the control was created on"

Comment: @Rico: Yes, of course. I can't believe that typo has been sitting there for the last three years and no-one noticing. Thanks for catching it, I updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: `!InvokeRequired` doesn't necessarily tell you if you are on UI thread or not. `InvokeRequired` is false even when you are on a different thread but the control's handle is not being created yet.

Answer (score 11):

bool isMessageLoopThread = System.Windows.Forms.Application.MessageLoop;

Comment: This is the simplest answer for my purposes.

Answer (score 7):

There is no answer for WPF yet, so for the record, in WPF you can use the return value of `Application.Current.Dispatcher.CheckAccess()` to know if you are on the GUI thread or not.

It returns `true` if the current thread is the UI thread in WPF.

Answer (score 6):

Please see [Detecting running in Main Thread in C# library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/225545/detecting-running-in-main-thread-in-c-library)

Answer (score 4):

You could use any of these:

```
bool isUIThread1 = SynchronizationContext.Current != null;
bool isUIThread2 = Application.MessageLoop;
bool isUIThread3 = Thread.CurrentThread.GetApartmentState() == ApartmentState.STA;
```

For `SynchronizationContext.Current` to have a value, the first form should be shown. Its also possible to set`SynchronizationContext.Current` to something from non-UI contexts as well as to set it to null from UI context (this is often seen to by-pass UI deadlocks). So in a way it is not completely reliable.

`Application.MessageLoop` is a better choice but that again requires the message pump to be started (i.e. first form shown).

`GetApartmentState` can be used in your `Main` method, even before showing any form but you need `[STAThread]` set on `Main`. It would be extremely rare for serious applications to miss that. In a way this approach is the soundest.

For all practical purposes you can use any of those.